# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}})$

Tags: limits

> $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}})$$

When $n\rightarrow \infty $ Then last term i. e $(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2n+1)}})\rightarrow (\sqrt{2}-1)$

Could some help me to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}})
&=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\sum_{r=1}^n\,\log\left(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}}\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\,\log\left(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}}\right)\right),
\end{align}

provided the limit exists of course.
For a series $\sum a_n$ to converge, we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.
This clearly fails here: as $r\to\infty$ we have

$$\log\left(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}}\right)\to\log\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)<0,$$

so the series diverges to $-\infty$.

---

In general, calculating an infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ is closely related to the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log c_n$.
The argument shows that in order for some infinite product to converge to a nonzero limit we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=1$.

Much like the case for series, this is a necessary but not sufficient condition.
If $\log c_n \to 0$, we will have $c_n \to 1$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log c_n$ may still fail  to converge.
In this case, $\prod_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ will also fail to converge.

Comment: if the log series diverges at $-\infty$ the product converges to 0, am I wrong?

Comment: You are correct, because $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\exp x = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$0\le \prod^{n}_{r=1}(\sqrt{2}-2^{\frac{1}{(2r+1)}})\le\prod^{n}_{r=1}(\sqrt{2}-1)=(\sqrt{2}-1)^n\to0$$

thus by squeeze theorem the limit is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You've got it. $0 < \sqrt 2 -1 < 1,$ so the limit will be $0$.  For example, after some point, the factors will all be $< 1/2,$ so it doesn't matter what the factors before that point were.

I'll just point out that by the usual definition of infinite products, we would **not** say $$\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}{\sqrt2 - 2^{\frac{1}{2r+1}}} = 0.$$  The definition is adjusted to make it true that an infinite product converges $0$ if and only if one of the factors is $0$. The technical details are unimportant, and it is certainly true that the limit of the partial products, as shown in your question, converges to $0$.